# How do upgrade pip3 when xenial says it's already installed but jupyter says it's not?

Tags: apt, python, jupyter

Context: Xenial, pip3, jupyter

I'm trying to install `jupyter` which depends on `pip3`. `Jupyter` says to install it, but `apt` says I already have the most recent version installed.

What goes on here?

```
bugmagnet@Phenomenon2:~$ pip3 install jupyter
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip

bugmagnet@Phenomenon2:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

bugmagnet@Phenomenon2:~$ pip3 install jupyter
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: I wonder if you might find it easier to install juypter via anaconda or some other system? Otherwise you could install `ipython3`/`ipython3-notebook`. Installing through pip requires you to also get `numpy` and `scipy` installed correctly, which is a massive pain.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with `jupyter`. It's your system that's failing to find the `pip3` command.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, that's weird.

I didn't have `python3-pip` installed on my system, and when I installed it, `pip3` worked.

Maybe you've managed to break the install somehow. Try `apt install --reinstall python3-pip`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
pip2 install virtualenv
virtualenv jupyter
source jupyter/bin/activate
pip2 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

This solution was tested on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial.
It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook
```

[snap shot: teminal and Frefox on xenial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MogdI.png)